# Wrong Activity is getting openned on clicking Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

After clicking on notification, wrong Activity is being oppended - main application activity, but not my goal Activity - NearPhotoActivity.

creating Notification:

```
    public static Notification createNotification(Location location) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                "3000", "notification_channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        return buildNotification("Notification Title",
                "Notification Body",
                true,
                R.drawable.ic_mr_button_connecting_00_dark,
                createPendingIntent(NearPhotoActivity.class, location),
                mChannel);
    }
```

creating PendingIntent:

```
    private static PendingIntent createPendingIntent(Class destinationActivityClass, Location location) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyApplication.getAppContext(),
                destinationActivityClass);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("nearLocation", location);
        return PendingIntent
                .getActivity(MyApplication.getAppContext(),
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    }
```

Activity that should be openned:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public class NearPhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView nearPhotoImageView;
    private TextView locationDescriptionTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_near_photo);

        onNewIntent(getIntent());


        nearPhotoImageView = findViewById(R.id.nearPhotoImageView);

        locationDescriptionTextView = findViewById(R.id.locationDescriptionTextView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getExtras().containsKey("nearLocation")) {
            Location location = (Location) intent.getExtras().getSerializable("nearLocation");
            //Address address = MyAppUtils.getLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
            locationDescriptionTextView.setText("You are " + location.distanceTo(MyApplication.getCurrentLocation()) + " meters");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong activity is opened because you have set `MainActivity` as default  in `Mainfest` when app is launched.

You should add `onNewIntent` function in `MainActivity`, but not in `NearPhotoActivity`.

**MainActivity**

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    receiveIntent(intent)
}

fun receiveIntent(intent: Intent?) {
   Location location = (Location) intent.getExtras().getSerializable("nearLocation");
   Intent i = newIntent(MainActivity.this,NearPhotoActivity.class)
   i.putExtra("location",location)
   startActivity(i)
}
```

Then use `getExtra` to get the `location` in `NearPhotoActivity` class.

Comment: There is no sense in processing onNewIntent in my MainActivity because I need extra in NearPhotoActivity, bacause location feeds TextView component from there.

Comment: I guess it will return `JSON` instead of location object ?

Comment: No, it will return valid Location object, now everything works fine.